# How can I check if file exists using patterns?

Tags: sh

I have a directory with full svn backups named like this:

```
name1.20100412.r9.bz2
name1.20100413.r10.bz2
name2.20100411.r101.bz2
name3.20100412.r102.bz2
...
```

I need to check if a backup file exists using name and revision number only. I tried `test` but it didn't work:

```
if [ -e name1.*.r9.bz2 ]; then echo exists; fi
[: too many arguments
```

How can I test if file exists?

Comment: What does `echo name1.*.r9.bz2` say? It looks like you have more than one revision 9 backup there!

Comment: Good answers there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6363441/check-if-a-file-exists-with-wildcard-in-shell-script . Simplest way: use `ls`. Best way: use `find`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check if the shell has expanded the pattern. This works in `sh` and `bash`:

```
pattern="name1.*.r9.bz2"

if [ "$(echo $pattern)" != "$pattern" ]; then
    echo exists
fi
```

P.S. If the pattern itself can be a valid filename, you can add a `-e` check:

```
if [ -e "$pattern" -o "$(echo $pattern)" != "$pattern" ]; then
    echo exists
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```
shopt -s nullglob
set -- name1.*.r9.bz2
if [ -n "$1" ]; then echo exists; fi
```

or

```
pattern="name1.*.r9.bz2"
if [ "$(echo $pattern)" != "$pattern" ]; then echo exists; fi
```

**Edit:** Added `shopt -s nullglob`.

Answer (score 2):

A slight variation on eugene y's answer:

```
test "$(echo name1.*.r9.bz2)" != "name1.*.r9.bz2" && echo exists
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
if ls name1.*.r9.bz2 &> /dev/null ; then
  echo exists
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like

```
FILES=(`ls name1.*.r9.bz2`)
if [ ${#FILES[@]} -gt 0 ]; then
  echo "Files!"
else
  echo "No Files"
fi
```

Comment: Produces ugly messages on stderr when the files do not exist.

Answer (score -1):

Related post:
[Check if a file exists with wildcard in shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6363441/check-if-a-file-exists-with-wildcard-in-shell-script)

It seems to have a good answer, using the return value of ls.