# test if file(s) from a given pattern exists in bash

Tags: bash, scripting

How do I test if a file (or many) named from given pattern exists and do stuff based on that test?

This is my failed attempt:

```
[[ { ls ../outputListWorkerPid_* |  wc -l } -ge "1" ]] && echo "ARRRRRR" || && echo "FAIL"
```

But I got the following error:

```
bash: conditional binary operator expected
bash: syntax error near `ls'
```

Also it would be nice to avoid the `No such file or directory` from `ls` in case the doesn't exists.

Comment: Does this answer help you at all?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6363441/check-if-a-file-exists-with-wildcard-in-shell-script

Answer (score -1):

Use an if-statement:

```
if [ "$(ls *.txt | wc -l)" -ge "1" ];
then
  echo "Yes";
else
  echo "No";
fi;
```

Does that answer your question?

Comment: If there are no *.txt files I get "ls: cannot access *.txt: No such file or directory"