# Need to check if .gz files exist in a directory

Tags: bash, shell

I have a prompt in my shell script where the user can choose a directory. I am trying to make it so that if a .gz file exists in that directory, they exit the loop, and if not, the user is asked again to choose a directory, but it just isn't working. Here's what I have so far:

```
ls -d */
while :
do
echo "Which Directory do you want to access?"
read input_variable1
cd $input_variable1
if [ CHECK FOR .gz ]
then
break
else
ls -d */
echo "no .gz files to unzip. Try again."
fi
done
```

Comment: This is not dup!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test supports using wildcards, so `[ -f *.gz ]` will be true if there is one file matching `*.gz` (and false otherwise - as @tripleee pointed out, this will fail with multiple matches; see below for a better variant).

Another possibility is to use `if ls *.gz &>/dev/null; then ...; else ...; fi` (which will not throw any errors).

Comment: Thanks! Helped a lot

Comment: But it will fail with a syntax error if there is more than one matching file.

Comment: @tripleee True, I've updated the response to include a version that won't fail.

Comment: The command substitution is quite superfluous there.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6363441/check-if-a-file-exists-with-wildcard-in-shell-script