# Set java_home, but ignore error

Tags: java, macos

On my Mac (El-Capitan), I have added the following command into my bash_profile file:

`export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home)"`

This perfectly sets the correct java_home environment var. However, on one of my machines I don't have java installed and I don't want to install java :).

I have a dotfiles repository, so on all of my machines I have the same .bash_profile file. Now the problem is that on the machine without Java, the command above outputs this:

`Unable to find any JVMs matching version "(null)".
No Java runtime present, try --request to install.`

Now my question is: how can I get rid of the error / warning, without changing the meaning of the command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably packing it into an if-statement, checking if java is actually installed? something like this:

```
if ls /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/j* 1> /dev/null 2>&1; then
  export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home)"
fi
```

This uses the return code of `ls` (thanks to this question/answer: [Check if a file exists with wildcard in shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6363441/check-if-a-file-exists-with-wildcard-in-shell-script)) to figure out if there are any files or directories starting with a j (like `jdk1.8.0_92.jdk` or `jre1.8.0_92.jre`). And only if such a JDK/JRE exists, it tries to export JAVA_HOME.