# Bash: Check If A Command Returns A Certain Value

Tags: linux, bash, shell, conditional-statements, ls

I am trying to write a `.sh` script where at a certain point it checks if there are one or more files in the current directory matching `*\_??\_??\_64kbs.mp3`

OR, using regex `^.*\_..\_..\_64kbs\.mp3$`

This is one attempt at the command:

```
if [ 'ls *_??_??_64kbs.mp3 2>/dev/null | wc -l ' == 0 ];
then echo "nothing";
else echo "something";
fi
```

I know that

```
'ls *_??_??_64kbs.mp3 2>/dev/null | wc -l'
```

in this case returns just the number 9 to the terminal, because there are 9 matches. If I remove the first '?', it then returns 0, like it should because there are no file names matching that expression. But the output of the if expression above is always "something".

EDIT:
Someone asked for a complete sample file name for what I'm trying to match. Here's one:

```
George-1983_1A_01_64kbs.mp3
```

Comment: Can you give a complete sample file name as an example?

Comment: have a look on `$?`

Comment: Just added a sample file name to the question, Inian.

Comment: Aif, I don't understand your suggestion.

Comment: you're checking wheather the string `'ls ....'` is equal to `0`, which it never is.

Comment: You're right. I tried wrapping the command with a $('command') earlier and it seemed to be causing errors but now it is working fine. Perhaps at the time I hadn't included '2>/dev/null' in the command and that was causing the issue.

Comment: @MatthewJendrasiak: Refer my answer using both `glob` and `regex` matches, which is the right approach here.

Comment: Dont use `ls` to find files. Use `find` instead.

Comment: Also take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6364244/5092659

Comment: @Aif That's an antipattern, scripts should very rarely need to examine `$?` directly.  The flow control constructs all examine this variable behind the scenes so you don't have to.  So `cmd; if [ $? == 0 ]; then`... is better written `if cmd; then`...

Answer (score 1):

You are clearly confusing with a *glob* with a *regex* match, `*` is a pure glob construct which can be used in a loop as below

```
fileNamePattern="*_??_??_64kbs.mp3"
for file in *.mp3; do
    [[ $file == $fileNamePattern ]] && echo "$file matches"
done
```

The meaning of `?` and `*` are different when used in a `regex` context, where we use `.*` for matching up to a part and `.{}` to represent any character whose occurence can be dictated by the value inside `{}`, for example,

```
fileNameRegex=".*_.{2}_.{2}_64kbs.mp3"
for file in *.mp3; do
    [[ $file =~ $fileNameRegex ]] && echo "$file matches"
done
```

The `~` is the `bash` regex operator (supported from `bash` version `4.0` onwards) you need to match a *regex* and not a *glob*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and this works, but I was clearly 'not' confusing glob with regex. You can see at the beginning of my question I suggested an equivalent regex to the glob I was using in the example. It's the same as yours except I explicitly write .. instead of .{2}, and I prefaced it with a ^ and ended it with a $.

Comment: @MatthewJendrasiak: Appreciate it! Thought with both the glob and regex approaches used, there was some confusion around. If this solved your problem, don't forget to upvote and accept it to make it helpful for future readers.

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution that seems to be working. Wrap the command in a $() instead of quotes.

```
if [ $(ls *_??_??_64kbs.mp3 2>/dev/null | wc -l) == 0 ];
then echo "nothing";
else echo "something";
fi
```

I tried something like this earlier and it didn't seem to work but there must have been a syntax error. In this case it is working.

Comment: This is clearly not the right way to go, Parsing output of `ls` is generally not recommended, see [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: to shed some light on the possible syntax error seems you tryed `'ls ...'` (the literal string "ls ...") `$('ls ...')` (the output of a command named "ls ....", files and therefor commands my have blanks in them) never `$(ls ...)` or `\`ls ...\`` (both work).

Comment: Also piping to `wc -l` is a very common antipattern.  See http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#wc