# Prevent loop that iterates over files that match pattern to try to loop over literal pattern?

Tags: bash, for-loop, wildcard

I have a loop that iterates over a series of text files (all are in the form `name.txt`):

```
for txt in *txt; do
    sed -i '$ d' $txt 
done
```

But whenever there is no `.txt` file in the directory, I get the following error message:

> sed: can't read ‘*txt’: No such file or directory

Comment: did you mean `sed -i '$ d' $txt`

Comment: Yes, that was a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this issue in two ways:

a) check for file existence before doing anything with it

```
for txt in *txt; do
  [[ -f "$txt" ]] || continue # skip if file doesn't exist or if it isn't a regular file
  # your logic here
done
```

b) use the shell option `shopt -s nullglob` which will make sure glob expands to nothing when there are no matching files

```
shopt -s nullglob
for txt in *txt; do
  # your logic here
done
```

---

See also:

- [Why is nullglob not set by default](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204803/why-is-nullglob-not-default)

Answer (score 0):

It's because it isn't matching any files and is leaving the 'txt' instead of doing what you expect which is to skip the for-loop. On some implementations (e.g. macOS), it will leave the string as '*txt' and run the for-loop with the variable txt set to *txt. You need to test for the existence of the file pattern first before attempting to run the for-loop. See [Check if a file exists with wildcard in shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6363441/check-if-a-file-exists-with-wildcard-in-shell-script).