# How do i extract the date from multiple files with dates in it?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Lets say i have multiple filesnames e.g. R014-20171109-1159.log.20171109_1159.
I want to create a shell script which creates for every given date a folder and moves the files matching the date to it.
Is this possible?

For the example a folder "20171109" should be created and has the file "R014-20171109-1159.log.20171109_1159" on it.

Thanks

Comment: Sure it's possible. What did you try, and where are you stuck?

Comment: I don't know how to extract the date with an regular expression.

Comment: Provide some code samples that you tried or maybe some tutorials you tried to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a typical application of a `for-loop` in bash to iterate thru files.
At the same time, this solution utilizes GNU [[ shell param substitution ]](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html).

```
for file in /path/to/files/*\.log\.*
do

  foldername=${file#*-}
  foldername=${foldername%%-*}
  mkdir -p "${foldername}" # -p suppress errors if folder already exists
  [ $? -eq 0 ] && mv "${file}" "${foldername}" # check last cmd status and move

done
```

Answer (score 0):

Below commands can be put in script to achieve this,

Assign a variable with current date as below ( use ***--date='n day ago'*** option if need to have an older date).

if need to get it from File name itself, get files in a loop then use ***cut*** command to get the date string,

```
dirVar=$(date +%Y%m%d) --> for current day,

dirVar=$(date +%Y%m%d --date='1 day ago') --> for yesterday,

dirVar=$(echo $fileName | cut -c6-13)   or
dirVar=$(echo $fileName | cut -d- -f2) --> to get from $fileName
```

Create directory with the variable value as below, (***-p*** : create directory if doesn't exist.)

```
mkdir -p ${dirVar}
```

Move files to directory to the directory with below line,

```
mv *log.${dirVar}* ${dirVar}/
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to write a shell script, use commands. To get date, use cut cmd like ex:

```
cat 1.txt 
R014-20171109-1159.log.20171109_1159
 cat 1.txt | cut -d "-" -f2
```

Output

```
20171109
```

is your date and create folder. This way you can loop and create as many folders as you want

Comment: Or just `cut -d "-" -f2 1.txt` to avoid a [very common bad habit](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html) ;)

Answer (score 0):

Its actually quite easy(my Bash syntax might be a bit off) -

```
for f in /path/to/your/files*; do

## Check if the glob gets expanded to existing files.
## If not, f here will be exactly the pattern above
## and the exists test will evaluate to false.
[ -e "$f" ] && echo $f > #grep the file name for "*.log." 
#and extract 8 charecters after "*.log." .
#Next check if a folder exists already with the name of 8 charecters. 
#If not { create}
#else just move the file to that folder path

break
done
```

Main idea is from this post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6363441/check-if-a-file-exists-with-wildcard-in-shell-script). Sorry for not providing the actual code as i havent worked anytime recently on Bash