# If statement comparing variable to files in list

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, emulation

I am using terminal emulator. I have a folder with save files in it and am trying to determine whether the entered text matches any file in the list.

I created a variable called `saveFiles` using the `ls`. Only displaying files with `.save` and removing it from the output:

```
saveFiles=$(cd "${0%/*}"/save; ls *.save* | ls *.save*; cd "${0%/*}")
echo -n ">"
read -r "name"
```

So `$saveFiles` equals:

```
Savegame1 savegame2 savegame3
```

I'm trying to make an if statement that tests wether the entered variable equals any of the files in the folder.

The following script works except when I type a letter contained at the end of the file. So if one of the files is called savegame, if I type game it comes up with a match because game.save is contained in the string.

```
if [[ $saveFiles = *"$name".save* ]]
then
   scene=$(cat "save/$name".save)
fi
```

I need to find a way to test wether any of the strings in `$saveFiles` are equal to the entered variable `$name`.

To reiterate, files in folder:

```
Save1.save
Save2.save
...

Read `$name`
```

If `$name` matches any file in the list then load scene otherwise repeat.

I hope this isn't confusing. Please feel free to ask me to clarify further. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to the StackOverflow! You can format the programm code in your question better with the grave accent character  ` ( for example `code`) or tripple ``` for multi-line code blocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I am not understanding the question correctly, but why don't you first request the file name and then query the file system with precisely that name, e.g.

```
read name
if [[ -f "${name}.save" ]];
    echo "Found the file ${name}.save"
fi
```

Comment: The issue is when I type a save that is not in the list it sets the game to a non existent file name. I will see if this works.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Just to clarify. How does this query work. -f is find right. So it's asking whether a file in the folder is matches name?

Comment: Ok I see it's saying if the search matches the filename. I'm glad it was that simple. This worked beautifully. Thank you.

Comment: Great :-)
For reference: I just fixed a typo - `read name` instead of `read $name`.

Comment: Yeah I didn't see that. I had a further question. Is there a way to use the same -f query to test whether or not a file in the list contains .save? Trying to make a if statement returning "No saves in folder"

Comment: I know I could do it by setting my ls variable with saveGame = ls /save and then an if statement for if saveGame contains .save. but it seems like there is a shorter -f script for wether a folder contains files with .save in the name.

Comment: However when I use :                                           saveFiles=$(cd "${0%/*}"/save; ls \*.save\*;) when the folder is empty I get this output:           ls: \*.save\*: No such file or directory. I don't want it to say this. The variable should just be set to null. So looks like I still need an if [ -f ] script for if files contain .save else echo "no saves".

Comment: I think, the simplest approach is to check the return value of `ls *.save` as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/6364244/10984529. Note, how the output is redirected to make the statement silent.

Comment: That worked perfectly: ```cd "${0%/*}"/save;  
  if ls *.save 1> /dev/null 2>&1``` How exactly is this script working? I'd like to know what `1> /dev/null 2>&1` scecifically means broken down.