# Bash scripting: Checking multiple file conditions in loop

Tags: bash, loops, conditional-statements

I'm writing a bash script to do something if the directory has files of extensions: jpg, jpeg or png. But I'm screwing up when I try to check this with the for or while loops.

```
while [ filename in $IMAGE_DIR/*.jp*g -o filename in $IMAGE_DIR/*.png ] ; do
        # do something here
```

But I receive compile error:

> line 30: [: too many arguments

I tried the following loops to no avail.

```
for (filename in $IMAGE_DIR/*.jp*g) || (filename in $IMAGE_DIR/*.png); do
while [ filename in $IMAGE_DIR/*.jp*g ] || [ filename in $IMAGE_DIR/*.png ] ; do
while [[ filename in $IMAGE_DIR/*.jp*g ]] || [[ filename in $IMAGE_DIR/*.png ]] ; do
while [[ filename in $IMAGE_DIR/*.jp*g ] || [ filename in $IMAGE_DIR/*.png ]] ; do
while (( filename in $IMAGE_DIR/*.jp*g )) || (( filename in $IMAGE_DIR/*.png )) ; do
while ( filename in $IMAGE_DIR/*.jp*g )) || (( filename in $IMAGE_DIR/*.png ) ; do
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Why don't you `do_something *.jpg *.jpeg *.png` if there aren't any, you will do_nothing. Or use `find -name "*.jpeg"` or any other pattern you want for their name, and `xargs` them to your job. There is no reason to check all the filenames around, the shell offers you these files with one command or one glob.

Comment: You want to `do something if the directory has files of extensions` or do you want to _iterate_ over these files? If this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6363441/check-if-a-file-exists-with-wildcard-in-shell-script ?

Comment: @KamilCuk: just want to iterate over these files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the way I believe it's easier to iterate multiple "types|extensions" of files. I hope with that you have an idea how to continue, you can create your if conditions inside that for loop.

```
$ ls -l
-rw-rw-r--  1 lucas lucas    0 Sep 25 13:58  test.jpeg
-rw-rw-r--  1 lucas lucas    0 Sep 25 13:58  test.jpg
-rw-rw-r--  1 lucas lucas    0 Sep 25 13:58  test.png
-rwxrwxr-x  1 lucas lucas   62 Sep 25 13:59  test.sh

$ cat test.sh 
#!/bin/bash
for i in *.jpg *jpeg *.png; do
  echo "hi $i"
done

$ ./test.sh 
hi test.jpg
hi test.jpeg
hi test.png
```

Comment: `echo "hi $i"` would prevent problems with word splitting and special characters in filenames.

Comment: @BenjaminW. You're right. I will improve the sample, thank you

Comment: without `shopt -s nullglob` you will get the patterns when no files exists. I advise `for ....; do if [ ! -e "$i" ]; then continue; fi; .... done`

Answer (score 1):

You are use `readarray` Instead of ".txt" just put any extension you want.

```
readarray FILES <<< "$(find . -name "*.txt")";
for file in ${FILES[@]}; do
    echo $file
done
```

Comment: Isn't that just a more complicated way of writing `for file in *.txt`? It also descends into subdirectories, which may or may not be desired.