# Script does not work with ` but works in single command

Tags: bash, awk

In my bash, the whole script won't work... When I use `

My script is

```
#!/bin/bash

yesterday=$(date --date "$c days ago" +%F)

while IFS= read -r line
do

dir=$(echo $line | awk -F, '{print $1 }')
country=$(echo $line | awk -F, '{print $2 }')

cd path/$dir

cat `ls -v | grep email.csv` > e.csv 

done < "s.csv"
```

Above output is blank.

If i use ""

output is `No such file or directory`

but if I use only 1 line on the terminal it works

```
cat `ls -v | grep email.csv` > e.csv
```

I also try with / , but didnt work either...

Comment: Copy/paste your code into http://shellcheck.net, fix the issues it tells you about, and then let us know if you still have a problem and post the corrected code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should generally [avoid `ls` in scripts.](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Also, you should generally prefer the modern POSIX `$(command substitution)` syntax like you already do in several other places in your script; the obsolescent backtick `` `command substitution` `` syntax is clunky and somewhat more error-prone.

If this works in the current directory but fails in others, it means that you have a file matching the regex in the current directory, but not in the other directory.

Anyway, the idiomatic way to do what you appear to be attempting is simply

```sh
cat *email?csv* >e.csv
```

If you meant to match a literal dot, that's `\.` in a regular expression.  The `?` is a literal interpretation of what your `grep` *actually* did; but in the following, I will assume you actually meant to match `*email.csv*` (or in fact probably even `*email.csv` without a trailing wildcard).

If you want to check if there are any files, and avoid creating `e.csv` if not, that's slightly tricky; maybe try

```sh
for file in *email.csv*; do
    test -e "$file" || break
    cat *email.csv* >e.csv
    break
done
```

Alternatively, look into the `nullglob` feature of Bash. See also [Check if a file exists with wildcard in shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6363441/check-if-a-file-exists-with-wildcard-in-shell-script).

On the other hand, if you just want to check whether `email.csv` exists, without a wildcard, that's easy:

```sh
if [ -e email.csv ]; then
    cat email.csv >e.csv
fi
```

In fact, that can even be abbreviated down to

```sh
test -e email.csv && cat email.csv >e.csv
```

As an aside, `read` can perfectly well split a line into tokens.

```
#!/bin/bash

yesterday=$(date --date "$c days ago" +%F)

while IFS=, read -r dir country _
do
    cd "path/$dir"   # notice proper quoting, too
    cat *email.csv* > e.csv
    # probably don't forget to cd back
    cd ../..
done < "s.csv"
```

If this is in fact all your script does, probably do away with the silly and slightly error-prone `cd`;

```sh
while IFS=, read -r dir country _
do
    cat "path/$dir/"*email.csv* > "path/$dir/e.csv"
done < "s.csv"
```

See also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable).

Comment: I was joking... The actual code is too long.. If i change here with ls, i need to make many changes... but the one using break is new to me... 

in loop i never do cd back. becaue each time loop run i 1st enter in dircetory by full path...

Comment: If you want to check for the literal file name `email.csv` without the need for any wildcards, that's a lot easier; see updated answer now. See also the note about entirely avoiding `cd` near the end.